# Is there a way to use replaceAll on string but call method for replacing the text on each occurrence of a match

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I want to replace all occurrences of particular string with different UUID's. For example,

```
content = content.replaceAll("xyz", "xyz" + generateUUID());
```

but problem here is that all the `"xyz"`'s will get replaced by same UUID. But I want that each `"xyz"` gets replaced by an individual unique ID. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (for efficiency, since `String` is immutable), a `while` loop and something like

```
// content = content.replaceAll("xyz", "xyz" + generateUUID());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(content);
String toReplace = "xyz";
int toReplaceLen = toReplace.length();
int pos;
while ((pos = sb.indexOf(toReplace)) > -1) {
    sb.replace(pos, pos + toReplaceLen, generateUUID());
}
// content = sb.toString(); // <-- if you want to use content.
```

Comment: If I use your method my while loop will get stuck in infinity. because I would like to replace the string with string + UUID so for e.g. "xyz" to "xyz" + UUID

Comment: @Nick add an index to the call of indexOf. Also, please edit your question; because that's not what it says.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Well editing the code my own a little bit solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)). This will give you the `replaceAll` functionality of a complete regex (not just a static `String`). Here, I use `uidCounter` as a very simple `generateUUID`; you should be able to adapt this to your own `generateUUID` function.

```
public class AppendReplacementExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int uidCounter = 1000;

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("xyz");
    String test = "abc xyz def xyz ghi xyz";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while(m.find()) {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group() + uidCounter);
      uidCounter++;
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
abc xyz1000 def xyz1001 ghi xyz1002
```

Comment: Using `m.group()` (an untrusted user input) inside a `appendReplacement` is unsafe, as `appendReplacement` does procesing based on the group to replace patterns like `$0` with the first group. To feed untrusted userInput to `appendReplacement`, replace all `\\` by `\\\\`, then replace `$` by `\\$`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you'd like a way to say something like this:

```
content = content.replaceAll("xyz", x -> x + generateUUID());
```

Here's an adaptation of durron597's answer that lets you do almost that:

```
content = replaceAll(content, "xyz", x -> x + generateUUID());

public static String replaceAll(String source, String regex, 
        Function<String, String> replacement) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement.apply(matcher.group(0)));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note that using a `StringBuilder` is better for performance than using a `StringBuffer`, as `StringBuffer` uses locks internally